Emulator process for AVD Pixel 7 has terminated
I think I'm going crazy. I've looked at numerous StackOverflow posts to no avail. Basically when I'm trying to launch Pixel 7 emulator, it throws an error: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_7_API_35 has terminated.
Before this problem, the Pixel 7 with API 35 worked fine, I think what might've happened was that somewhere data was being cached that eventually corrupted something/everything that's what I've seen during my research at least.
Within idea.log located in C:/Users/<Me>/AppData/Local/Google/AndroidStudio2024.2/log/ it does not specify what it exactly failed it.
2024-11-11 10:41:06,145 [  23326]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 API 35 - Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
2024-11-11 10:41:06,145 [  23326]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 7 API 35 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819
2024-11-11 10:41:07,014 [  24195]   WARN - #com.android.sdklib.deviceprovisioner.DeviceAction - The emulator process for AVD Pixel_7_API_35 has terminated.
com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$EmulatorTerminatedException: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_7_API_35 has terminated.
  at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$WaitForEmulatorTask.run(EmulatorConnectionListener.java:93)
  at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport$executeOnPooledThread$1.run(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:134)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
  at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextCallable.call(ContextCallable.java:32)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at com.intellij.util.concurrency.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:27)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

When running ./emulator -avd Pixel_7_API_35 within the specified folder log looks like this:
INFO    | Graphics backend: gfxstream
INFO    | Found systemPath C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-35\default\x86_64\
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO    | IPv4 server found: ************
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: *******************************
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: *******************************
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: *******************************
INFO    | Critical:
INFO    | Warning:

Things I've tried and nothing worked:

Reinstalling the emulator from tools
Creating advancedFeatures.ini with vulkan = off
Setting Graphics Settings to Hardware
Cold booting
Wiping data
Creating other emulators
Even swapped the image to without Google Store support

Could it be Java related? Mind, we're running on a VM machine, working with Windows/WSL but surely that cannot be at fault as Android Studio is being ran on Windows.
